# BeanUtils class usage

Tags: java, class, object

```
public static Object createObject(String className, Map params) throws Exception {
        Object role = ObjectUtils.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(className).newInstance();
              if (params != null) {
            Iterator it = params.entrySet().iterator();
                  while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                String paraName = (String) entry.getKey();
                String paraValue = (String) entry.getValue();
                BeanUtils.setProperty(role, paraName, paraValue);
            }
        }
        return role;
    }
```

What are all the different usages of BeanUtils. 
What is BeanUtils.setProperty actually doing here.

After execution of above lines of code. 
How will be the value of role will be.
Anyone kindly explain It will be much helpful.

Comment: Did you look at a javadoc for `BeanUtils`?

Comment: S i do. but i cant understand

Comment: OK, then make it clear which part you don't understand, so we can clarify it for you.

Comment: thanks in advance. what is the value of role when it is got returned.. what are all the paraName and paraValue doing inside role.

Comment: I was in the process of composing an answer. Please have more patience.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the value of role when it is got returned

`Object role` is an instance of a class whose name is `className`, as loaded by the classloader of ObjectUtils. Constructed reflectively (using the no-argument constructor **only**)

> what are all the paraName and paraValue doing inside role.

The map called `Params` contains a bunch of name->value mappings, detailing the properties to be set on `role` (which is just an object with a bunch of getters and setters, designed to comply with the [Java Bean specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)

By iterating the map, we can get a list of all of the name->value mappings that we should set. For each, we call [`BeanUtils.setProperty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#setProperty%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Set the specified property value, performing type conversions as required to conform to the type of the destination property.

All this does is update the value of fields/members of `role`.

Comment: Thanks a lot..so Whether paraName is filled with a value called paraValue?? and paraName comes with role object right?

Comment: @MSIbrahim Somewhat. The map called `params` specifies fields of `role` to fill. For example, if `params` mapped `foo->123` and `bar->456`, it would be equivalent to calls being made such as `role.setFoo(123)` and `role.setBar(456)`.